# NodeNotFoundError when migrate but can't find the corresponding migration

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am getting this error on migrate.
`django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration basket.0002_auto_20140827_1705 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'partner', u'0001_initial')`

I have two subapps - one myoscar, the other mysub. In mysub folder, my migration folder doesn't even have a `basket.0002_auto_20140827_1705`.

In myoscar folder, there isn't a migration folder. What would cause this error?
I tried creating a basket folder under oscar to see if there is migration folder popping up, nothing.

[update]

```
INSTALLED_APP = [...]
+get_core_apps(['myoscar.partner' ]) 
#also tried adding 'myoscar.basket', also tried rearranging the order
```

also tried forking the basket, found `basket.0002_auto_20140827_1705`, commented out `(u'partner', u'0001_initial')` to see what happens. Same error.

[edit] myapp is really myoscar. made corrections above

path

```
App
|--app
|----__init.py__
|----settings.py
|----urls.py
|--myoscar
|----basket  #just forked this
|-------migrations #has 0002_auto_20140827_1705, removed error line. Shows same error. 
|----dashboard
|----partner
|----myoscar
|----templates
|--mysub
|----migrations
|----static
|----templates
```

Comment: What does your `INSTALLED_APPS` look like?

Comment: @Wyatt I do have `+get_core_apps(['myapp.partner' ])  also tried adding `myapp.basket`but same error. I also updated my question to other things ive tried.

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: @Wyatt ive updated my paths.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to override Oscar's `partner` app with your own. In that case, you would need to have the same migrations in your `partners` app as Oscar's `partners` app (i.e., you would probably want to start by "forking" the `partners` app).

Comment: Also, both `oscar.apps.basket` and `oscar.apps.order` depend on the `partner.0001_initial` migration, so you would get a similar error from the `order` app.

Comment: @Wyatt ahh! Thank you and for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to delete all **pycache** and migrations folders. This is a hack and I'm not sure it is the correct way to go around this. But it worked.
After deleting those folders, makemigrations for each app explicitly then migrate.